# Unclear ansible variable formatting

Tags: ansible

When formatting variables in ansible playbooks which format should be followed?
I cannot for the life of me find a straight answer for this?

```
environment:
    - http_proxy: "{{ {{ proxy }} if {{ proxy }} != '' else {{ ansible_local.proxy_facts.proxy }} }}"
    - http_proxy: "{{ proxys if proxy != '' else ansible_local.proxy_facts.proxy }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *`ternary`* filter. For example

```yaml
- set_fact:
    http_proxy: "{{ (proxy|length > 0)|
                     ternary(proxy, ansible_local.proxy_facts.proxy) }}"
```

[Don't compare to empty string](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/blob/master/lib/ansiblelint/rules/ComparisonToEmptyStringRule.py)